# Is it possible to add a shadow to the outside of a Chrome App window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have an app that is a standalone window. I want to add a box shadow around the window (so it appears on top of all windows behind it). Is this possible?

Comment: I don't thinks it's possible. I think it's the OS's job to do that, if it can and the user chooses so in the OS UI preferences.

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko I know Google was talking about allowing transparent window capabilities (which would allow this) in Chrome apps, did that ever happen?

Comment: Yes, it's been proposed, and seems to be in the coding stage now. Depending on how it's implemented, it might suit your needs with a certain amount of manual work to emulate the shadow.

Comment: Sergey: Wanna add your comment as an answer, since it is correct with the addition that there is additional stuff coming to the API soon?

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko if you make your comment the answer (hopefully with a link to chromium site where they're working on that code), I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @BenWells FYI, if you don't do the person's name with an `@` synbol in front of it, they won't get a notification about your message. :)

Comment: @Don thanks for the tips, I'm still getting used to SO. After your comment I looked up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work as I'd been wondering about the details....

Comment: @BenWells The one thing I don't like is that you can only "@" one person per comment/post.

Comment: @DonRhummy: Interestingly, I didn't get any notification in my email (although I did in my SO inbox). I've asked the folks working on this new API about the expected availability and what will/won't be possible with it with regard to window shadows. When they come back to me, I'll post the detailed answer below.

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko Thanks! Hope it'll work across all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[posting this answer based on the discussion in the comments to the original question]

There is a [Shaped and Translucent Windows API](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/document/d/1BwU__X2WEayBwa2Su0o4FYrGSqlqcC5q8lQigfTCYCI/edit#heading=h.w8inspeo32bj) coming to Chrome apps soon.

This API should be able address your needs at least to a good extent. It is already available under an experimental flag in M32 for Windows and Chrome OS.

The current state of the implementation is as follows.

The input region / window shape API is partially complete for Windows & CrOS:
- on Windows it implements window shaping.
- on CrOS it implements input region shaping but doesn't yet affect the visible shape.

In M33 Linux should gain window shape support, and we hope to have CrOS window shape, and the transparency limiting based on shape landed as well.

Transparency outside the window shape will likely only work on CrOS initially, due to limitations of the platform specific shape APIs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this as the answer but it does appear to be a bit in flux so we'll see if this remains. It is a bit of a shame to have features different on the platforms since the promise of Chrome apps is about having the same experience across multiple platforms with one code.